# Laravel class property not returning in response

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating an API for a blog using Laravel and in my UserController, for some routes, I get the currently authenticated user as seen below:

```
public function getUser() {
$user = auth()->user();
return response()->json($user, 200);
}
```

This returns a json object of the user. I get the user in other functions in the same way. I wanted to move this line into a wider scope so I could access it in all functions so I placed it in the constructor:

```
    class UserController extends Controller {
        protected $user;
        public function __construct() {
          $this->user = auth()->user();
        }
      }
```

I refactored getUser to look like this;

```
public function getUser() {
    return response()->json($this->user, 200);
    }
```

Now it just returns an empty object and the 200 status code. Why does making it a class property no longer return the object?

Comment: You can't use `auth()` in the constructor because the authentication is checked after the controller is constructed

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session middleware has not ran yet; the Controller is instantiated before the Request goes through the middleware stack, so you won't have access to session based authentication at that point (so `auth()->user()` would be `null`). You can use a Controller middleware to do this though:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    protected $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $this->user = $request->user();

            return $next($request);
        });
    }
}
```

This middleware will run after the other middleware in the stack so you will have access to the session at that point.

Comment: Assigning a value in the constructor is not required, to begin with - not even the property makes sense. Your approach isn't wrong at all, but it's rather clutter (based on the question) than "clean code".

Comment: It is what the OP is asking for in their question (take it up with them), i am answering their particular question not some general question

Comment: Getting error in lumen 8 `Illegal offset type`